# Sorting between groups based on a variable other than the one grouped on

Tags: python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I would like to use Pandas groupby to sort groups according to a value within each group. This value is not the one used for the grouping.

I am working with public transport data which tells me the stops and arrival times of different bus trips. Here is a sample of the dataframe (called `stopTimes`):

```
trip_id stop_sequence   arrival_time
1       3               15:08:00
2       2               16:01:00
1       1               09:00:40
2       3               16:45:00
2       1               07:05:30
1       2               12:03:00
```

I would like to sort the trips according to the arrival time at the first stop. So the result of the sorting for the above dataframe would be:

```
trip_id stop_sequence   arrival_time
2       1               07:05:30
2       2               16:01:00
2       3               16:45:00
1       1               09:00:40
1       2               12:03:00
1       3               15:08:00
```

I have been able to achieve this result already by:

```
timeSortedTrips = stopTimes.loc[stopTimes['stop_sequence']==1].sort_values('arrival_time')['trip_id']
stopTimes['trip_id'] = pd.Categorical(stopTimes['trip_id'],timeSortedTrips)
stopTimes = stopTimes.sort_values(['trip_id','arrival_time'])
```

However, I am curious: can I achieve this using groupby? If so, would it be more efficient? Additionally, I am new to Python, so if you have even better ideas to do this sorting please point me in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby `trip_id` and within each group, sort by `arrival_time`

```
stopTimes.arrival_time = pd.to_datetime(stopTimes.arrival_time)
stopTimes = stopTimes.groupby("trip_id", as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort("arrival_time"))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work and I couldn't immediately find why. I get this error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why. It worked for me. Could you try sort_values instead of sort.